# Why travis-ci.org always show [ build : failing ] badge?

Tags: c, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

All last builds are **[#passed](https://travis-ci.org/Argentumbolo/SPB_dialog_C/builds)** but travis always show the **[ build : failing ]** badge for my [test project](https://github.com/Argentumbolo/SPB_dialog_C).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks fine now. How did you solve it? Sometimes it might be cache issue.

Comment: I don't know. In github page right bage now but in travis-ci.org it still shows as [ build : failing ].

Maybe some number of people had look at github page and cache has been reloaded?

Comment: Personally, I see "passing" both on Github and [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/Argentumbolo/SPB_dialog_C).

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug see https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8389. The bug is been closed by the stale bot but has not been fixed yet as of 2020-07.