# Why is Travis CI showing failing build icon althought build is passing ?

Tags: travis-ci

Since yesterday, when I go to https://travis-ci.org/bamthomas/aioimaplib the badge is green at the very beginning of the page display. Then it goes red "failing" (after 1s or a bit less).

If I click on it, I have the "Status Image" popup, then it comes green again with "passing".

On the [github page](https://github.com/bamthomas/aioimaplib), the badge is red "failing".

If someone has a clue, I'm confused. 
Thank you

Comment: According to https://travis-ci.org/bamthomas/aioimaplib/branches your master branch is failing. As the last build is 0.7.12, you see a success on the travis-page but the badge refers to the master so 1. the github README will show failure and 2. I don't know why it turns red for you. My browser shows a nice shiny green badge on the link you give.

Comment: In short, get your master to pass and you should be ok for the badge :-)

Comment: :) thank you for your help. Okay, next time I'm going to see the branches tab. I relaunched a build from master and now it is green.

Comment: I dont understand either why it was green for you (on github or travis site ?). I know that sometimes I've had browser cache issues with the badge display on github.

Comment: on travis I landed on the last build that was 0.7.12, I don't know why you had the red badge there :-/

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011816/why-travis-ci-org-always-show-build-failing-badge/62737244